# GitHub pipeline run conditional step isn't working

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, pipeline

I have a GitHub pipeline.

I want to run a step conditionally.

I'm running on `fix_bug` branch

**My code:**

```
  - name: Run Step
    if:  ${{ contains(github.ref, 'bug_fix') || github.ref == 'fix_bug' }}
    run: |
```

**Excepted result:**

Should run the step (or enter into the step).

**Actual result:**

Doesn't enter into the step.

The step has the didn't run sign.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
  if:  ${{ contains(github.ref, 'bug_fix') || github.ref == 'refs/heads/fix_bug' }}
```

resolved the issue, but anyone know to tell why I should the prefix `refs/heads`?

Tnx

Comment: why you should what with the prefix `refs/heads`?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're wanting to use `github.ref_name` (the branch or tag name) that triggered the workflow.

`github.ref` will look something like

- `refs/heads/<branch name>`
- `refs/pulls/<number>/*`
- `refs/tags/<tag>`

you can see some examples by running `git ls-remote <your repo url>`

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context